# A country/website selector page before home page in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am working in a Magento website. I need a interim page before the home page, user will see the country/region splash screen first time and they select the country/region, and they move to real website content according to the specific country/region. Is there any way to do this in Magento?

**Edit**

It should be a landing page not a modal box that appears in home page.

Comment: Use js modals (with cookies for first time run) on homepage

Answer (score 0):

Add a new store view as ***interim store view*** with own CMS Home page and set it as ***default store view***. On its ***CMS Home page*** add the country/region selector with redirects for each page.

If you want no header or footer add also a new template for this interim store view with empty header and footer or with the desired content on those sections.